# Running jobs at boot-up

Tags: boot, cron

I'm new to this whole Linux thing and I was wondering. I know about cron // crontab and I want to run a a job after boot.

The jobs I'd like to run are:
1 - apt get update && apt get upgrade -y (from what I understand, crontab is owned by the root so there is no need to use the su // sudo command which is good, since mixing crontab and sudo is a bad idea)

2 - Open a vpn connection:
openvpn <file_name>.ovpn

From what I saw, the command should be as follows:
@boot <command 1>
@boot <command 2>

Could you fellas help me out? Is this the right way? Is the syntax correct? I don't want to mess-up a cronjob.

Thank you

Comment: You can do it, but Unattended Upgrades does most of that already. Some non-Ubuntu sources should NOT be automatically upgraded, lest they break your system. Opening a VPN connection should be done through systemd, so you are sure that the network is up before starting.

Answer (score 0):

The `@boot` cron job is really hit and miss. Using systemd would be a consistent way to have this task performed. However, I believe “unattended upgrades” are what you’re looking for. This will have security updates automatically installed for you, no reboot required. This will leave your other installed software intact.

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

You can test it afterwards with:

```
sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run
```

Comment: Unattended Upgrades is already included with every install of Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Can you explain (or point to an explanation of) how to use `systemd` in order to automatically perform a user task after the other things (mainly network) are up and running?